# Return all Duplicates except first occurrence in Object Array with multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I want to be able to loop through and array of objects and return all duplicated results excluding the first instance of the object by selecting multiple values are checks.

Here is my attempt:

```
const things = [ {
    location: 'Lynnwood, Wa',
    keyword: 'Video Production',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659a55783fad6667853dd4' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597e4783fad6667853d8b' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597cc783fad6667853d8a' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597c7783fad6667853d89' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597c2783fad6667853d88' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597c2783fad6667853d87' },
  { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659288783fad6667853d86' },
  { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659219783fad6667853d84' },
  { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659218783fad6667853d83' },
  { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659218783fad6667853d82' } ];

function getDuplicates(arry) {
    var duplicates = [];

    arry.forEach((item, index) => {
        if(arry.indexOf(item.location) != index && arry.indexOf(item.keyword) != index) {
            duplicates.push(item);
        }
    });

    return duplicates;
}


   /*
   Expected Result: (Excludes first occurance of dup but returns the rest)
   [
   { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597cc783fad6667853d8a' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597c7783fad6667853d89' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597c2783fad6667853d88' },
  { 
    location: 'Las Vegas',
    keyword: 'Cleaners',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c6597c2783fad6667853d87' },
    { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659219783fad6667853d84' },
  { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659218783fad6667853d83' },
  { 
    location: 'Lagos, La',
    keyword: 'Top Home',
    user: null,
    profile: null,
    id: '5c659218783fad6667853d82' }
   ]
   */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is by using an array that holds all of the unique items you have found, basically functioning as a set.

The key is that if an item isn’t in that set then it is added to it, and NOT added to duplicates (as it is the first and possibly only occurrence).

The .some array method really comes in clutch for deep object comparison (acting kind of like a .includes here).

With this in mind, the code below is very simple and can definitely be condensed/enhanced with maybe another array method or something.

```
let uniqueItems = []
arry.forEach(item => {
  if(uniqueItems.some(other => 
        item.location === other.location
        && .... && ... && ....
        )){
       duplicates.push(item)
  } else {
       uniqueItems.push(item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a copy of the array, by using [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The **`slice()`** method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```
function getDuplicates(arry) {
    ...
    arry.slice(1, ).forEach((item, index) => {
    ...
        }
    });

    return duplicates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with an array and object.

Array to keep desired output, object to keep track of first occurrence of element.

```js
const things =[{location:'Lynnwood,Wa',keyword:'VideoProduction',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c659a55783fad6667853dd4'},{location:'LasVegas',keyword:'Cleaners',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c6597e4783fad6667853d8b'},{location:'LasVegas',keyword:'Cleaners',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c6597cc783fad6667853d8a'},{location:'LasVegas',keyword:'Cleaners',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c6597c7783fad6667853d89'},{location:'LasVegas',keyword:'Cleaners',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c6597c2783fad6667853d88'},{location:'LasVegas',keyword:'Cleaners',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c6597c2783fad6667853d87'},{location:'Lagos,La',keyword:'TopHome',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c659288783fad6667853d86'},{location:'Lagos,La',keyword:'TopHome',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c659219783fad6667853d84'},{location:'Lagos,La',keyword:'TopHome',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c659218783fad6667853d83'},{location:'Lagos,La',keyword:'TopHome',user:null,profile:null,id:'5c659218783fad6667853d82'}];

let desired = []
let included = {}

things.forEach((inp)=>{
  if(included[inp.keyword]){
    desired.push(inp)
  } else {
    included[inp.keyword] = true
  }
 
})

console.log(desired)
```